# Need reference site/material for angular and neo4j integration

Tags: node.js, angular, neo4j

I am working on `angular` application with `neo4j` database.

I didn't find any good reference material about `angular` and `neo4j` integration.

Looking for advice/info/links to docs on the above.

Answer (score 1):

official repo for angular and neo4j
https://github.com/webmaxru/angular-neo4j

see this project
https://github.com/adadgio/neo4j-js-ng2